# Можно ли с IPv6 адреса обмениваться пакетами с IPv4 адресом?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, сокет

На сервере есть только внешний `IPv6 адрес`, выданный провайдером. С этого сервера сокетом надо отправить запрос и получить ответ с удаленного `IPv4 адреса`, это возможно? Если да, то какими способами? Использовать:
   `IPAddress.MapToIPv6()`, `IPAddress.MapToIPv4()`?

Comment: Отправить запрос и получить ответ по какому протоколу? TCP?